# Find the limit of $\tau(k^n)^{\frac{1}{n}}$

Tags: sequences-and-series, limits, number-theory, solution-verification

Find the limit of $lim_{n \to \infty} \tau(k^n)^{\frac{1}{n}}$

Let $k=p^{r_1}\cdots p^{r_m}$.Then $k^n=p^{nr_1}\cdots p^{nr_m}$.

Then $\tau(k^n)=(nr_1+1) \cdots (nr_m+1)$.

Then $(\tau(k^n))^{\frac{1}{n}} = (n^{\frac{1}{n}})^m (r_1 \cdots r_m)^{\frac{1}{n}}(r_1+ \frac{1}{n})^{\frac{1}{n}}\cdots (r_m + \frac{1}{n})^{\frac{1}{n}}$

Then $\lim_{n \to \infty} (\tau(n))^{\frac{1}{n}}=1$

Is my approach correct?